# Fixed width gap between two Div's

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have ideas how to get gap between two divs fixed?
I have one main content Div and inside it there are two Div's with pictures. View is 768px wide and when I start to stretch the view, two pictures start to move away from each other. But ideally main content Div should stretch with whitespace around and pictures should remain with fixed gap between them.

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
        <h2 class="title-two" id="portfolio">PORTFOLIO</h2>
      <div class="column-left left">
         <img src="images/picture1.png" class="first">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <p>Text field</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-left right">
         <img src="images/picture2.png" class="first">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <p>Text field</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-right left">
         <img src="images/picture3.png" class="first">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <p>Text field</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-left right">
         <img src="images/picture4.png" class="first">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <p>Text field</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media  (min-width: 768px) {

 .left {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 47%;
    padding-left: 2%;
 }

 .right {
    display: block;
    float:right;
    width:  47%;
    padding-right: 2%;
 }
}
```

Also same problem is in header where text and icon start to move away from each other, although their space between should remain same.

I have read that flexbox should help, but when I set display to flex, all pictures are in random places.

Comment: create example on jsfiddle

Comment: Why not use absolute values and margin? margin-right:3px or sth like that

Answer (score 2):

use margin-left and margin-right in your css

```
@media  (min-width: 768px) {

 .left {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 47%;
    margin-left: 2%;
 }

 .right {
    display: block;
    float:right;
    width:  47%;
    margin-right: 2%;
 }
}
```

Comment: When I add margin left and right, it pushes pictures under each other because width is bigger than 100%. But when I delete padding and put just margin, the effect is same - columns start to move from each other, although their gap should remain ~10px and edges should stretch out.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin-right and margin-left. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/96ru7gsk/). As you can see, there is a gap between the divs.

```
.right{
margin-right: 2%;
}

.left{
margin-left: 2%;
}
```