# Arrange DIVs adjacent to each other and flip each of them with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flip

Please see the image below.

[image]

Hovering over a `DIV` should flip it, revealing different content (the 'back' of the 'card'.)

With the relevant code below, I've managed to

- get the arrangement shown by the coloured `DIV`s, but not adjacent to each other, like the whites.
- get the flip animation from the **beginning** of each `DIV`, while should be from the **center** of each `DIV`.

For the flip animation, I used [this](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) resource. For the `DIV` placement, I used, among others, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742952/fixed-width-gap-between-two-divs).

`Relevant HTML`

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Website</title>
      <script src="my.js"></script>
      <script src="jq_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bs/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
      <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet'>
      <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster Two' rel='stylesheet'>
      <script src="bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "javascript: isLoggedIn();">
      <div class="container">
        :
        :
        :
        :
        <div  id="results">
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Relevant CSS`

```
/* Dealet Card */
.dealet-container
{
  /*display: inline-flex; */
  perspective: 1000px;  
}

.dealet-container, .front, .back
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
}

.dealet 
{
    /*width: 18%;*/
    margin-left: 14px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    transition: 0.9s;
}

.dealet:hover 
{
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
/*  transform: rotateY(180deg);
*/}

.dealet-container:hover .flipper, .dealet-container.hover .flipper 
{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper
{
  transition: 0.9s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front
{
  z-index: 2;
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
}

.back
{
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back
{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
}

.dealet_box 
{
  padding: 6px 6px;
}

.dealet_img
{
  width: 100%;
}

.dealet_logo
{
  width: 60%;
}

.dTop
{
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  font-size: 16px; 
}

.dBot
{
  font-family: 'Lobster Two';
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

`Relevant JavaScript / JQuery`

```
function drawCard(myArray)
{
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
  resultsDiv.innerHTML = "";

  var html = [""];

  $.each(myArray, function(cardNum, value)
  {
    dealet = myArray[cardNum].dealet;
    dealetID = "dealet" + cardNum;
    dTopID = "dTop" + cardNum;
    dBotID = "dBot" + cardNum;

    logo = myArray[cardNum].logo;
    addr = myArray[cardNum].address;
    mob = myArray[cardNum].mobile;

    // Card front
    htmlFString = [  '<div class="dealet-container">',
              '<div class="flipper">',
              '<div class="dealet front" id=f' + cardNum + '>',
                      '<img id="' + dealetID + '" src="' + dealet +  '" class="dealet_img">',
                      '<div class="dealet_box">',
                        '<span class="dTop" id="' + dTopID + '">' + myArray[cardNum].name_top + '</span><br>',
                        '<span class="dBot" id="' + dBotID + '">' + myArray[cardNum].name_bottom + '</span>',
                      '</div>',
                      '</div>'
                     ].join('');
    // Card back                     
    htmlBString = [ '<div class="dealet back" id=b' + cardNum + '>',
                      '<img src="' + logo +  '" class="dealet_logo" align="center">',
                      '<div class="dealet_box">',
                        '<span>' + addr + '</span><br>',
                        '<span>' + mob + '</span>',
                      '</div>',
                      '</div>',
                      '</div>',
                      '</div>'
                     ].join('');
    html += htmlFString;
    html += htmlBString;
  });

  resultsDiv.innerHTML = html;

} // of drawCard()
```

Greatly appreciate if someone can look in and help complete what I've set out to. Been stuck for sometime now. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [This website](https://www.myrbetriq.com/cost-savings-and-support/) has a similar flip card layout that maybe you could use to learn.

Comment: @James, precisely what I am looking for, thanks! Will answer this question myself soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! Got the desired result finally.

To place `DIV`s adjacent to each other, this is the style that worked. The `display` and `flex-flow` elements clinched it.

```
/* Dealet Card */
.dealet-container
{
  display: inline-table; 
  perspective: 1000px;  
}

.dealet 
{
    margin: 14px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
```

For the flip animation, the `z-index` for the 'back' of the 'card' was the clincher. This is what worked (Ref: [CSS Layout: The Position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)):

```
.back
{
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this is of help to someone. Thanks to all who looked in!